# How to resolve errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, php

```sql
CREATE TABLE `account_transfers` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_account_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_account_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_account_transfer` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(25,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `is_cancelled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `upload_token` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `options` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `account_transfers_from_account_id_foreign` (`from_account_id`),
  KEY `account_transfers_to_account_id_foreign` (`to_account_id`),
  KEY `account_transfers_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAIN[...]
```

> #1005 - Can't create table `lotusukl_lotusschool`.`account_transfers` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: The server will not understand the syntax that you came up with. Study [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: You need to show us the whole `CREATE TABLE` statement that fails, not just a part of it.

Comment: When defining FKs, the tables must be `CREATEd` in the proper order.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Tables don't exist in isolation - they may depend on other tables - as you know because you're trying to create a `FOREIGN KEY`. However, there's a major problem - **either** your referenced table doesn't exist yet, **or** you don't have a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on the referenced field! **We can't tell** and nor **can we help you** until you provide **all** of the **relvant** parts of the db creation script! As  mentioned, order is important - you can't create a `FOREIGN KEY` on a table which doesn't exist yet!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the parent table and key:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`from_account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`)
```

<sup>**Note:** I don’t know if `account` is the correct parent. Be sure to define it based on your database schema.</sup>

Specifying the name of the key is not required, though you can if you really, really want to.